# DOTA 2 borderless window moved down

Tags: games

I am pretty new to ubuntu but just switched as I realized that my favorite game is supported in linux. I have a 2560 * 1080 screen and want to play the game in 1920*1080. That works by settings the game to borderless window.

Now my issue: ubuntu's top-bar moves the dota window down, which causes the bottom ledge of the game to be moved off the screen.Now I am unable to move the camera ingame as I need to move the mouse to the screen ledges.

Is it possible to move the game-window above the top-bar?
Moving the window while holding ALT renders the game below the top bar.

edit:/

Screenshot of the game in a smaller resolution than 1920*1080 so you see everything it includes:

[image: Small resolution]

Screenshot of the game in 1920*1080:

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot

Comment: done @AndroidDev

Comment: @Marv While you wait for a solution here, I encourage you to file an issue at https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues and see if you can get help there too.

Comment: @Marv Cool, I saw your issue. I would also recommend you to add a link to your post here because you have screenshots here that will help devs better understand what the problem is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no fix for this available. [According to Valve](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues/1022), they are working on improving the HUD to support bigger screen sizes.

**Update**

Valve updated the HUD (a while ago) which allows playing the game on the full screen without any further issues.

Comment: In full screen mode is not possible to scroll right. Do you know how to fix it? I think it's because of left gnome panel.